# Using Filter on the names of a named vector is returning an empty named vector, despite the predicate being true?

Tags: r, names

Consider `out<-setNames(sample(26,replace = T),letters)`. By construction, one of the elements of the output must be named `a`. However, when I try `Filter(function(x) names(x)=="a",out)`, I get a named numeric of size 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: It would be better if you provide the content of `letters`. Are letters in *lower-case*?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes. `letters` is built-in to every version of R that I've ever used.

Comment: Sorry, I miss that.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `Filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `Filter` loses the naming information of the vector (because it use `lapply` internally on `out` which also loses this information).

However, you can filter the names using: `out[names(out) == "a"]`.
The result is a vector containing `6` with the name `a`.

Comment: How do you know that `lapply` is to blame? `Filter` calls it, but I can't see where this behavior is documented for `lapply`.

Comment: I just ran `lapply(out, names)` which return a named list of unnamed vector (the list itself is names with the one of the vector). The thing is that the `names` call does not apply on the list names, but to the vector in the list that are unnamed, hence the NULL value described in the post of Rui Barradas. So, `lapply` seems fine to me, but not its use in `Filter`. However, as long as naming is undocumented, it is unfortunately difficult to say if this behavior is intended or not.

Comment: Are you sure that the elements of `out` don't have names? `example<-out[1]` definitely has the expected name and code like `lapply(out,function(x) x+20)` does not appear to drop the expected names. Something deeper seems to be going on.

Comment: I tried to experiment with the `USE.NAMES` argument of `sapply`. It had the same behavior as `lapply`. I hoped that it was the right tool for the job, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in `Filter`. Or, at least, an undocumented behavior. The function argument `x` is not a named integer, the `names` attribute is stripped:

```
Filter(function(x) {
  print(names(x))
  names(x) == "a"
}, out)
#NULL
#NULL
#NULL
#NULL
# (... a total of 26 NULL's...)
#NULL
#NULL
#NULL
#NULL
#named integer(0)
```